# Create PDF document with content on drive using HTTP requests

Tags: pdf, google-drive-api

I faced curious issue when was trying to create pdf file with content using google drive api.

What I do is actually sending HTTP request with following details:

Method: POST
Endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart
Headers: Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="foo_bar_baz"
Body request:

```
--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
"name": "file20.pdf",
"description": "Description 20"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/pdf

Hello World 20 
--foo_bar_baz--
```

As a result I get created file20.pdf in the root of my drive with necessary content (I can see it with file preview function), BUT when I try to open the file as a google doc I see notification: "Failed to load other pages", "Failed to view file". However, if I try to download the created file I can not see the content.

"Hello World 20" is content of the pdf file

Can anybody help me to figure out the issue?
P.S. I going to create pdf file with HTML markup, so it is important to use exactly application/pdf type.

Comment: What is `Hello World 20` in your request body?

Comment: This is content of the pdf file

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `This is content of the pdf file`, I think that `Hello World 20` is not PDF data. In your actual situation, `Hello World 20` is replaced with the valid PDF data, and the request body including the valid PDF data is requested. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Hello World 20 is what I want to see inside my file

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Yes, you are correct. Hello World 20 is what I want to see inside my file`, if your actual request body is the actual PDF data instead of a text of `Hello World 20`, I think that your request body works. So, I cannot understand your current issue. I apologize for this. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue using your actual request body instead of a text of `Hello World 20`? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: This is my actual current request body. I just want to format my request body to get created correct pdf file with content "Hello World 20"

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I asked `About This is content of the pdf file, I think that Hello World 20 is not PDF data. In your actual situation, Hello World 20 is replaced with the valid PDF data, and the request body including the valid PDF data is requested.`, you said `Yes, you are correct.`. But, in your reply, you say `This is my actual current request body.`. So, I'm confusing understanding your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, when I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: My question is why created file is corrupted after I submit this request